# Password not working

Tags: iphone, email, password

Today, out of the blue, my iPhone kept poping up a message that said my password was incorrect for my email account. I went to settings and reentered the password (I'm 100% sure this is the correct password). But the message kept popping up.

I tried to go my Apple password and have a link sent by email to change my password. But no email ever arrived. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please provide us more information about your iPhone (iOS version, type,...) and your mail account (type, hoster,...)

Answer (score 2):

Try to rule out the causes... Go to your inlog page of your mail account on your pc and try with your password. If you can access the mailbox, then you know it's your iPhone. If you can't, it's you.

If you can access your mailbox on the web, then make sure you've configured your mail-account correctly. You can always try Google to search for a setup for your e-mail client. For example "How to configure hotmail with iPhone", or so.

And as a last resort, you can delete your mailbox and re-add it. Your iPhone will automatically rebuild your inbox, so nothing will be lost.

[image]

If you're using a POP-account (like hotmail), I could recommend an IMAP-account (like GMail).